# Security of /home/.ssh/authorized_keys against spoofing with mount

Tags: security, sshd

How is sshd secured against spoofing the home folder with the `mount --bind` command?

I did a test and and mounted the home folder with another folder on a different hard disk. After using the command ssh-copy-id from the client, the public key of the client was correctly imported into `/home/.ssh/authorized_keys` and after changing the access rights of the home folder with `sudo chmod 755 ~` it worked like a charm and it was not longer necessary to enter a password.

In my opinion it can be a risk to 'steal' the trust of a server. If you are able to reroute hostnames you can create a spoofed server.

Answer (score 3):

If you have root access, almost all other security is moot.

The only exception to this is if the directory is encrypted and the decryption key is not stored on the system.  Even then, root can subvert the system to capture your decryption key, it's just harder.